# How to assign a word a value then find the sum in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

i have found different formulas online but none have worked
i need late = 1 and early = 2

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | ________ |
| late     | early    | late     |

then in a table like this find the sum of the row

the answers should be 4 but i cant seem to find a formula in google sheets to get me the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=sum(switch(A2:C2,"late",1,"early",2,))
```

[image]